# how to make drop down menu show in front

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

My drop down menu blocked my comment tab. Any css / jquery can let the menu show in front ?

[image]

Comment: Since you've supplied a picture, and not code, I'd suggest Photoshop (hint, hint)

Comment: Please include your relevant HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting z-index value for the menu in CSS

```
li 
{
    z-index:10;
}
```

The tag with higher z-index value is shown above the ones with lower z-index value. [Read this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: thanks you so much ! totally saving my time with this super correct solution !